# ... there is no associate over whom he does not acquire the same right that he would grant others over himself

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

This is a little section from Rousseau's Social Contract,

"Finally, in giving himself to all, each person gives himself to no one. **And since there is no associate over whom he does not acquire the same right that he would grant others over himself**, he gains the equivalent of everything he loses, along with a greater amount of force to preserve what he was" *The Social Contract, Book I, Chapter XI*

I wonder what the bolded sentence actually means, as the grammar here is a bit complicated.

Can anyone provide a breakdown for the sentence-structure used here?

(this is a discussion on social agreement, associate here is an individual of an association, the right referred here is the right granted for being an associate)

Comment: A simpler version would be _He gets the same right over every associate that every associate gets over him_ - the implications of that depend on the context, of course. It could simply be seen as "he is now allowed to hit every other person, but every other person is also allowed to hit _him_".